# Random division of an array into equal sub (more than two) arrays in R

Tags: r

I need to divide my data (single variable) into multiple sub groups of equal size, but the division of the elements must be random.

```
   let x <- c(1:12)
```

and I want to divide it into three sub groups randomly

```
    G1<- (1,3,5,10)
    G2<- (2,6,11,7)
    G3<-(12,4,9,8)
```

Comment: You may separate your values into columns of a matrix: `matrix(sample(x), ncol = 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
x <- sample(x)
n_grps = 3
grps <- split(x, rep_len(1:n_grps, length(x)))

print(grps)

$`1`
[1]  1 12  8  9

$`2`
[1]  3 10  5  4

$`3`
[1]  6 11  7  2
```

Comment: Perhaps `sample(x)` instead of `x[sample(length(x))]`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's two parts to this - randomly shuffle your data, then break the vector apart into a list of (sub) vectors.

You can try something like the following:

```
x = rnorm(12)
nsplit = 3
split(x[sample(length(x))],rep(1:nsplit,each = length(x)%/%nsplit))
```

if your split doesn't divide evenly into the length of your array, there may be implementation details to take care of...but this is the gist.

p.s. not to be too pedantic but `x=1:12` doesn't need the `c()`